In VS Code, how edit the shortcut of moving to next line?
Earlier, I use Ctrl + Enter to next line and if need to move the text after the cursor to next line I use Shift + Enter.
But, now when I press Ctrl + Enter GitHub's Copilot suggestions comes and not being able to go to the next line.

it will be helpful if you share you current vsCode version, also provide the os and it's version.

This question is similar to: How can I change keyboard shortcut bindings in Visual Studio Code?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

VSCode doesn't work and did not work as you described in first place. Ctrl+Enter scrolls down by 1 line. Shift+Enter creates or extend selection down by one line.

You might have new keyboard shortcuts since the last update, which you can modify or delete.
Enter "Preferences: Open Keyboard Shortcuts" on the command palette, type Ctrl + Enter, remap or delete the mappings you do not want.

